# Bootstrap 3: toggle off-canvas navigation menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cloudflare

I have the following issue. I am developing a website using the Bootstrap3 framework to give it a nice responsiveness. In some of the pages I use the off-canvas navigation menu (example can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/). When developing locally, it works perfectly (if I make the screen's width small, the menu disappears, a toggle button appears and when clicked, the menu slides from the right).
The problem is when I try to do the same on the server (web hosting: fatcow.com). The toggle button will not trigger the menu sliding. (here an example video: http://screencast.com/t/8dZoW4gK)
When I use 'Inspect element' on Google Chrome, I see that there is some additional code added to the source code of the page.

http://screencast.com/t/59vze3aZd3m

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/abv=2545410587/cloudflare.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">.cf-hidden { display: none; } .cf-invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style>

<script data-module="cloudflare/rocket" id="cfjs_block_1313ed8fefd" onload="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_1313ed8fefd_load()" onerror="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_1313ed8fefd_error()" onreadystatechange="CloudFlare.__cfjs_block_1313ed8fefd_readystatechange()" type="text/javascript" src="http://esngreece.gr/cdn-cgi/nexp/abv=980862342/cloudflare/rocket.js"></script>
```

I have no idea why this code is added on the  section, but this is the only difference from the localhost, so I suppose there is a js conflict.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Rocket Loader is impacting it. Have you tried turning that off in your CloudFlare Performance Settings?

Comment: I also thought the same. The magic thing is that without deactivating it, it started working normally after some days. It could be some update on the server, or some cache, I have no idea..